# Segmentation fault on line with fgets() - C

Tags: c

I have this code in my program:

```
char* tok = NULL;
char move[100];

if (fgets(move, 100, stdin) != NULL) 
{
    /* then split into tokens using strtok */
    tok = strtok(move, " "); 

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        printf("Element: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

I have tried adding printf statements before and after fgets, and the one before gets printed, but the one after does not. 
I cannot see why this fgets call is causing a segmentation failure.

If someone has any idea, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: Did you use also a proper debugger next to adding prints before and after that line? Does it show a call stack somewhere in the system libraries or is the last location really in your program's function only? What platform/compiler?

Comment: You probably have a bug elsewhere in the program. It's corrupting the heap, and the error in `fgets()` is just a side effect.

Comment: Hey, I am still very new to C, so I am not sure how to do that (I'm a java programmer). I am using the GNU compiler on ubuntu, and I am using C99.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn. [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is the common debugger for Linux.

Comment: This code is correct. You must have a problem elsewhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In the effort to produce a MCVE you may discover for yourself where the bug is. Also, http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I have tested your code. It is correct. Could you please display your input?

Comment: I tested this code. I am also getting seg fault :(

Comment: I tested this on Windows 7 and ubuntu 14 and it works fine.  Please provide a complete code sample and exactly what steps you took which caused a segmentation failure as you call it.  what error exactly?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        char *tok = NULL;
        char move[100];

        if (fgets(move, 100, stdin) != NULL)
        {
                /* then split into tokens using strtok */
                tok = strtok(move, " ");

                while (tok != NULL)
                {
                        printf("Element: %s\n", tok);
                        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
        }
    }

Answer (score -2):

The strtok runtime function works like this

the first time you call strtok you provide a string that you want to tokenize

```
char s[] = "this is a string";
```

in the above string space seems to be a good delimiter between words so lets use that:

```
char* p = strtok(s, " ");
```

what happens now is that 's' is searched until the space character is found, the first token is returned ('this') and p points to that token (string)

in order to get next token and to continue with the same string NULL is passed as first argument since strtok maintains a static pointer to your previous passed string:

```
p = strtok(NULL," ");
```

p now points to 'is'

and so on until no more spaces can be found, then the last string is returned as the last token 'string'.

more conveniently you could write it like this instead to print out all tokens:

```
for (char *p = strtok(s," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
  puts(p);
}
```

**EDITED HERE:**

If you want to store the returned values from strtok you need to copy the token to another buffer e.g. strdup(p); since the original string (pointed to by the static pointer inside strtok) is modified between iterations in order to return the token.